# Atomic Sending and Receiving of Messages over RS232

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I have a peculiar problem.

A custom protocol which I need to use to communicate with a serial device works as follows, I'm using standard ASCII abreviations.

1. -> My program sends SOH to start transmitting
2. -> My program sends a packet of STX+data+ETX (I actually send both SOH and this packet in one go)
3. <- The device sends back an ACK to acknowledge he has received the packet
4. -> Now my program sends an EOT to signal end of transmission

If the message was a request expecting an answer, the device sends back data. Because the way `SerialPort.DataReceived` works I have to piece the received message back together manually.
It goes a bit like this:

1. <- Device sends SOH+STX+data
2. <- Device sends additional bytes, ending with ETX
3. -> My program sends ACK once the package has been received in its entirety
4. <- Device sends EOT

This is basically the way these two communicate, barring lost packets and NAKs and those things, but I don't want to make it too complicated.

My problem is: How do I wrap either the sending of a complete message or receiving of a complete message into an atomic operation? What I don't want is my program sending a new message while I'm in the middle of gluing a received message back together.

I have tried using `Monitor.Enter()` and `Monitor.Exit()` but the received event is called on a different thread, so no dice.

I have also tried using a `Semaphore` with only 1 resource, calling `semaphore.WaitOne()` at the start of either sending or receiving and calling `semaphore.Release()` after I have sent the EOT and after I have received an EOT from the device. This also doesn't work quite well.

Is there any way to do this better?

Comment: How can it recieve more data while you're in the middle of gluing the previous data back together? Does the last packet take a really long time to add or something?

Comment: If you want to wait for this transaction to complete then there's just no point in using the DataReceived event.  Just call the Read() method directly.  Don't forget to use ReadTimeout.

Comment: @minitech It's not that it receives more data while I'm gluing, just that sometimes a send can be issued over the same line while it's in between received packets. This is what I want to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a lock:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx

You can setup a global object say serialLock and use this to make sure that when you are glueing pieces together any send threads have to wait:

In the received

```
lock(serialLock)
{
//Glue data
}
```

In all send:

```
lock(serialLock)
{
// send data
}
```

This will sort any problems with different threads etc.

I would also make sure you have received a full message in the glue data section before releasing the lock. Maybe to make this cleared would be you will need to update a thread-safe data structure in the DataReceived event and in the glue data section you will need to stay in this section checking the data structure for a full message before releasing your lock.

Comment: I used that, but it's basically syntactic sugar for Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit which as I pointed out doesn't work. This is because different threads are trying to grab and release the lock. The data is received on a different thread, that's how DataReceived works.

Comment: The problem is that sending a complete message is spread out over "send, receive ACK, send EOT" so I get bounced between sending and receiving.

Comment: You don't put the lock in the DataReceived event you need another thread that clues the messages together. This isn't a simple fix you need to wait until you get a full message before sending the next which mean you need to manage the locking correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar problem when I wrote code to communicate with a GSM Modem over serial port.

I was able to develop a reasonably good solution by making use of [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) class in the `System.Threading` namespace. Basically, I made my Send method to wait for the ACK signal.

Here is a skeleton code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Sample
{
    public class SocketWrapper
    {
        #region Static Variables

        private static AutoResetEvent _SendWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        #endregion

        #region Member Variables

        private object _SendLockToken = new object();

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public void Write(byte[] data)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_SendLockToken);
            try
            {
                // Reset Handle
                _SendWaitHandle.Reset();

                // Send Data
                // Your Logic

                // Wait for ACK
                if (_SendWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000)) // Will wait for 1000 miliseconds
                {
                    // ACK Received
                    // Send EOT
                }
                else
                {
                    // Timeout Occurred
                    // Your Logic To Handle Timeout
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_SendLockToken);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // When ACK is received call SET
            _SendWaitHandle.Set();

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Note:
In DataReceived method, make sure that you don't call the Write method directly/indirectly, as this could result in a DeadLock.  Always start processing the received data on a different thread using `BackgroundWorker` or by the using the TPL.

Comment: Okay, this helps with sending messages, but I need another trick for receiving them. Because the receives are coming in parts, I can't just do `lock(myLock) { doStuff(); }` I need some way to keep that lock over multiple operations of DataReceived()

Comment: Also I need to make sure I'm not sending while receiving.

Answer (score 1):

I would define a 'SerialTxn' class that contains members for the request data, reply data, state-machine/s that encode/decode the protocol, timeouts, exception/errorMessage, OnCompletion(SerialTxn thisTxn) event/delegate, and anything else required for a complete transaction into one class.  Then I would get one, load it up with request data etc. and queue it, (BlockingCollection), to one thread that handles the serial port.  The thread gets the instance, calls its methods to tx and rx the data and calls the OnCompletion event/delegate when done.  This allows sync and async transactions - the OnCompletion event can either signal an Event, (AutoResetEvet maybe), that the originating thread is waiting on, or it can queue the reply back to some queue that the originating thread can process when it wishes.

Since only one thread ever handles the port, there is zero chance of any overlapping tx/rx operations.  The txn either succeeds completely or loads in an appropriate exception or error message into the SerialTxn.  If an error occurs, or the data needs to be sent on to a logger, GUI or whatever, all the relevant data is in one place in one object, ready to be queued off, BeginInvoked or whatever.

I don't like locking over lengthy operations...

Comment: *"Since only one thread ever handles the port..."* -- Totally agree, using a dedicated thread for each resource eliminates contention and need for a lock.  It's the simple trick for making cooperative (versus competitive/preemptive) systems work efficiently.